# How to change the lookup column in vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(R3,'Payment Term'!A2:B9,2,0)
```

and my lookup table is

[image]

So, now when I enter 1 in R3, I get 'Net' but I want the opposite behavior, I want to enter 'Net' and get the id but I am not able to find a way to do it. Is this even possible

Comment: vlookup works by finding first column values. You need xlookup if you are using Excel 2016. If not you need to use index() formula for that.

Comment: Do you mean `=INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(R3,$B$2:$B$9,0))` ?

Comment: @P.b was not aware of this, not much familiar with excel and spreadsheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `=XLOOKUP`

```
=XLOOKUP(R3,'Payment Term'!B2:B9,'Payment Term'!A2:A9,"not found",0)
```

A quite new formula that can be used instead of the `index/match`-combo

Comment: This worked, I was foolishly trying to make vlookup work instead of looking for alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `INDEX/MATCH` instaed of `VLOOKUP()` because vlookup always lookup value in first column. Try-

```
=INDEX('Payment Term'!$A$2:$A$9,MATCH(R3,'Payment Term'!$B$2:$B$9,0))
```

Comment: Will try this, for now xlookup worked